# How do I set up DNS on a LAN so web users don't need to use http://localhost...?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, internal-dns

I have deployed a web application to `http://localhost:8083/MyApp` on a local dev box. This is under the default web site. I would like to create a new web site and app pool, and have users access it via `http://MyApp`.

The simplest, but most work, solution is to add an entry to each client machines `hosts` file, but I would like to set up an internal, LAN, DNS for this, to look up `MyApp` and find the correct machine address and have happy and impressed userS.

How do I go about this? Does Windows 7 Pro have a DNS server available out the box; is there a free third party one IO can use; and what must I do with said DNS server? How many of what type records with what info must I create?

Comment: Google. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software

Comment: You will need to configure your dhcp server to give the dns ip to all your clients

Comment: How small? Why aren't the machines in a domain?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not running  a domain is my client's choice, not mine to question. I would if I were his IT provider, but I just write software for him.

Comment: In that case, you're at an impasse.